# One activity data is transferring to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I was in trouble with logical error somewhere in my program, what happening is when I use time picker and Switch in my MainActivity then the time selected and Switch state getting changed in my another activity i.e: UtilMainActivity which is a subclass. But whereas, when I change the switch state and time in my UtilMainActivity it is not resulting in a change of switch state and alarm time in my MainActivity.What I actually need is when I change alarm time and switch in MainActivity does not lead to change of time and switch in my UtilMainActivity.......Hope You understand my problem. Here is My MainActivity.

UtilMainActivity

```
public class UtilMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

SwitchCompat onOffSwitch;
TextView firstAlarmTextView;
TextView timeLeftTextView;
LinearLayout firstAlarmLayout;
UtilSharedPreferencesHelper sharPrefHelper;
UtilTimerManager utilTimerManager;
UtilAlarmParams utilAlarmParams;
BroadcastReceiver timeLeftReceiver;
private final String LOG_TAG = UtilMainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

final int ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 45;
final float DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION = 2f;  // number of alarms, first alarm, interval values text size is larger than text around them

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.utility_activity_main);
    onOffSwitch = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.switch_main);
    firstAlarmLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main_firstalarm);
    firstAlarmTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_main_firstalarm_time);
    timeLeftTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_main_timeleft);

    sharPrefHelper = new UtilSharedPreferencesHelper(UtilMainActivity.this);
    sharPrefHelper.printAll();

    utilAlarmParams = sharPrefHelper.utilgetParams();
    utilTimerManager = new UtilTimerManager(UtilMainActivity.this);

    showFirstAlarmTime(utilAlarmParams.firstUtilAlarmTime.toString());
    showTimeLeft(utilAlarmParams);

    onOffSwitch.setChecked(sharPrefHelper.isAlarmTurnedOn());


    onOffSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            utilAlarmParams.turnedOn = isChecked;
            if (isChecked) {
                checkNotificationPolicy();
                checkOverlayPermission();
                utilTimerManager.startSingleAlarmTimer(utilAlarmParams.firstUtilAlarmTime.toMillis());
                showToast(getString(R.string.utility_main_alarm_turned_on_toast));
            } else {
                utilTimerManager.cancelTimer();
                showToast(getString(R.string.utility_main_alarm_turned_off_toast));
            }
            showTimeLeft(utilAlarmParams);
            sharPrefHelper.utilsetAlarmState(isChecked);
        }
    });


    firstAlarmLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle timePickerBundle = new Bundle();
            timePickerBundle.putInt(UtilTimePickerDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_ALARM_HOUR, sharPrefHelper.utilgetHour());
            timePickerBundle.putInt(UtilTimePickerDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_ALARM_MINUTE, sharPrefHelper.utilgetMinute());

            UtilTimePickerDialogFragment timePicker = new UtilTimePickerDialogFragment();

            timePicker.setArguments(timePickerBundle);
            timePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), UtilTimePickerDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
    });

}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showTimeLeft(utilAlarmParams);
    timeLeftReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0) {  //i.e. every minute
                showTimeLeft(utilAlarmParams);
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(timeLeftReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (timeLeftReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(timeLeftReceiver);
    }
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
    UtilAlarmTime utilAlarmTime = new UtilAlarmTime(hour, minute);
    utilAlarmParams.firstUtilAlarmTime = utilAlarmTime;
    showFirstAlarmTime(utilAlarmTime.toString());
    showTimeLeft(utilAlarmParams);
    resetTimerIfTurnedOn();
    sharPrefHelper.utilsetTime(utilAlarmTime);
}

private void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(UtilMainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void resetTimerIfTurnedOn() {
    if (onOffSwitch.isChecked()) {
        utilTimerManager.resetSingleAlarmTimer(utilAlarmParams.firstUtilAlarmTime.toMillis());
        showToast(getString(R.string.utility_main_alarm_reset_toast));
    }
}


private void showFirstAlarmTime(String firstAlarmTime) {
    String wholeTitle = getString(R.string.utility_main_firstalarm_time, firstAlarmTime);
    SpannableString wholeTitleSpan = new SpannableString(wholeTitle);
    wholeTitleSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION),
            wholeTitle.indexOf(firstAlarmTime) - 1,
            wholeTitle.indexOf(firstAlarmTime) + firstAlarmTime.length(), 0);
    firstAlarmTextView.setText(wholeTitleSpan);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void showTimeLeft(UtilAlarmParams utilAlarmParams) {
    UtilAlarmTime utilAlarmTime = utilAlarmParams.firstUtilAlarmTime;
    timeLeftTextView.setText(getString(R.string.utility_all_time_left, utilAlarmTime.getHoursLeft(), utilAlarmTime.getMinutesLeft()));
    if (utilAlarmParams.turnedOn) {
        timeLeftTextView.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.primary));
    } else {
        timeLeftTextView.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.main_disabled_textcolor));
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Time left: "+ utilAlarmTime.getHoursLeft() + ":" + utilAlarmTime.getMinutesLeft());
}

private void checkNotificationPolicy() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
            && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings
                        .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

/**
 * needed for Android Q: on some devices activity doesn't show from fullScreenNotification without
 * permission SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
 */
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void checkOverlayPermission() {
    if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) && (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this))) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + this.getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    IntervalDialogFragment.IntervalDialogListener,
    NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment.NumberOfAlarmsDialogListener,
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

SwitchCompat onOffSwitch;
ListView alarmsListView;
TextView intervalBetweenAlarmsTextView;
TextView numberOfAlarmsTextView;
TextView firstAlarmTextView;
TextView timeLeftTextView;
LinearLayout firstAlarmLayout;
LinearLayout intervalLayout;
LinearLayout numberOfAlarmsLayout;
AlarmsListHelper alarmsListHelper;
SharedPreferencesHelper sharPrefHelper;
TimerManager timerManager;
AlarmParams alarmParams;
BroadcastReceiver timeLeftReceiver;
Button sleepTimer;
private final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

final int ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 45;
final float DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION = 2f;  // number of alarms, first alarm, interval values text size is larger than text around them

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    alarmsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_main_alarmslist);
    onOffSwitch = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.util_switch_main);
    intervalBetweenAlarmsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_main_interval);
    numberOfAlarmsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_main_numberofalarms);
    firstAlarmLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main_firstalarm);
    firstAlarmTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.util_textview_main_firstalarm_time);
    timeLeftTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_main_timeleft);
    intervalLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main_interval);
    numberOfAlarmsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main_numberofalarms);
    sleepTimer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sleepTimer);

    sharPrefHelper = new SharedPreferencesHelper(MainActivity.this);
    sharPrefHelper.printAll();

    alarmParams = sharPrefHelper.getParams();
    timerManager = new TimerManager(MainActivity.this);
    alarmsListHelper = new AlarmsListHelper(MainActivity.this, alarmsListView);

    showFirstAlarmTime(alarmParams.firstAlarmTime.toString());
    showTimeLeft(alarmParams);

    showInterval(sharPrefHelper.getIntervalStr());
    showNumberOfAlarms(sharPrefHelper.getNumberOfAlarmsStr());
    onOffSwitch.setChecked(sharPrefHelper.isAlarmTurnedOn());

    alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);

    onOffSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            alarmParams.turnedOn = isChecked;
            if (isChecked) {
                checkNotificationPolicy();
                checkOverlayPermission();
                timerManager.startSingleAlarmTimer(alarmParams.firstAlarmTime.toMillis());
                showToast(getString(R.string.main_alarm_turned_on_toast));
                sharPrefHelper.setNumberOfAlreadyRangAlarms(0);
            } else {
                timerManager.cancelTimer();
                showToast(getString(R.string.main_alarm_turned_off_toast));
            }
            alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);
            showTimeLeft(alarmParams);
            sharPrefHelper.setAlarmState(isChecked);
        }
    });

    intervalLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntervalDialogFragment dialog = new IntervalDialogFragment();
            Bundle intervalBundle = new Bundle();
            intervalBundle.putString(IntervalDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_INTERVAL, sharPrefHelper.getIntervalStr());
            dialog.setArguments(intervalBundle);
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), IntervalDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
    });

    numberOfAlarmsLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment dialog = new NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment();
            Bundle numberOfAlarmsBundle = new Bundle();
            numberOfAlarmsBundle.putString(NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_NUMBER_OF_ALARMS, sharPrefHelper.getNumberOfAlarmsStr());
            dialog.setArguments(numberOfAlarmsBundle);
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
    });

    firstAlarmLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle timePickerBundle = new Bundle();
            timePickerBundle.putInt(TimePickerDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_ALARM_HOUR, sharPrefHelper.getHour());
            timePickerBundle.putInt(TimePickerDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_ALARM_MINUTE, sharPrefHelper.getMinute());

            TimePickerDialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerDialogFragment();

            timePicker.setArguments(timePickerBundle);
            timePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), TimePickerDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
    });

    sleepTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openNewActivity();
        }
    });


}
public void openNewActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SleepTimerActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showTimeLeft(alarmParams);
    timeLeftReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0) {  //i.e. every minute
                showTimeLeft(alarmParams);
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(timeLeftReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (timeLeftReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(timeLeftReceiver);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final View view = findViewById(R.id.scheduleactivity);

            if (view != null) {
                view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                        // Do something...

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Scheduled Utilities Stopper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PrefActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.scheduleactivity: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, UtilMainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onIntervalChanged(String intervalStr) {
    showInterval(intervalStr);
    alarmParams.interval = Integer.parseInt(intervalStr);
    alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);
    resetTimerIfTurnedOn();
    sharPrefHelper.setInterval(intervalStr);
}

@Override
public void onNumberOfAlarmsChanged(String numberOfAlarmsStr) {
    showNumberOfAlarms(numberOfAlarmsStr);
    alarmParams.numberOfAlarms = Integer.parseInt(numberOfAlarmsStr);
    alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);
    resetTimerIfTurnedOn();
    sharPrefHelper.setNumberOfAlarms(numberOfAlarmsStr);
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
    AlarmTime alarmTime = new AlarmTime(hour, minute);
    alarmParams.firstAlarmTime = alarmTime;
    showFirstAlarmTime(alarmTime.toString());
    alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);
    showTimeLeft(alarmParams);
    sharPrefHelper.setNumberOfAlreadyRangAlarms(0);
    resetTimerIfTurnedOn();
    sharPrefHelper.setTime(alarmTime);
}

private void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void resetTimerIfTurnedOn() {
    if (onOffSwitch.isChecked()) {
        timerManager.resetSingleAlarmTimer(alarmParams.firstAlarmTime.toMillis());
        showToast(getString(R.string.main_alarm_reset_toast));
    }
}

private void showInterval(String interval) {
    String wholeTitle = getString(R.string.main_interval, interval);
    SpannableString wholeTitleSpan = new SpannableString(wholeTitle);
    wholeTitleSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION), wholeTitle.indexOf(interval), interval.length() + 1, 0);
    intervalBetweenAlarmsTextView.setText(wholeTitleSpan);
}

private void showNumberOfAlarms(String numberOfAlarms) {
    int numberOfAlarmsInt = Integer.parseInt(numberOfAlarms);
    String wholeTitle = this.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.main_number_of_alarms, numberOfAlarmsInt, numberOfAlarmsInt);
    SpannableString wholeTitleSpan = new SpannableString(wholeTitle);
    wholeTitleSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION),
            wholeTitle.indexOf(numberOfAlarms),
            numberOfAlarms.length() + 1, 0);
    numberOfAlarmsTextView.setText(wholeTitleSpan);
}

private void showFirstAlarmTime(String firstAlarmTime) {
    String wholeTitle = getString(R.string.main_firstalarm_time, firstAlarmTime);
    SpannableString wholeTitleSpan = new SpannableString(wholeTitle);
    wholeTitleSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION),
            wholeTitle.indexOf(firstAlarmTime) - 1,
            wholeTitle.indexOf(firstAlarmTime) + firstAlarmTime.length(), 0);
    firstAlarmTextView.setText(wholeTitleSpan);
}

private void showTimeLeft(AlarmParams alarmParams) {
    AlarmTime alarmTime = alarmParams.firstAlarmTime;
    timeLeftTextView.setText(getString(R.string.all_time_left, alarmTime.getHoursLeft(), alarmTime.getMinutesLeft()));
    if (alarmParams.turnedOn) {
        timeLeftTextView.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.primary));
    } else {
        timeLeftTextView.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.main_disabled_textcolor));
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Time left: "+alarmTime.getHoursLeft() + ":" + alarmTime.getMinutesLeft());
}

private void checkNotificationPolicy() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
            && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings
                        .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

/**
 * needed for Android Q: on some devices activity doesn't show from fullScreenNotification without
 * permission SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
 */
private void checkOverlayPermission() {
    if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) && (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this))) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + this.getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You have ```@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)``` on the ```UtilMainActivity```'s ```onCreate()```. I think maybe that could be the issue.

Comment: no that is not an issue

Answer (score 2):

Your activity, won't get the new data, because it's receiver was already unregistered, to make this easier for you, I would advise, you start the activity with `startActivityForResult` that way when you are done, you can set the data and the previous activity will receive the data in a `bundle` on this callback `onActivityResult(...)`

Comment: can i know this in detail i dont have any idea with this thing.Will you help me

Comment: I don't want to get data from one activity to another I need to stop that in my app.can i know this in detail I don't have any idea with this thing. Will you help me.

Comment: From your code, you are getting the state of the time switch from a shared preference `onOffSwitch.setChecked(sharPrefHelper.isAlarmTurnedOn());`

Comment: If I understand correctly you don't want the change done in MainActivity to reflect in UtilActivity, if so, then you should pick your values from the sharedprefs and set to the timepicker and switch

Comment: yes that is what but everthing is clear i am taking switch and time from utilsharedpreference not from mainactivity sharedprefs.

Comment: i am sending data to utilsharedpref and taking from utilsharedpref but getting problem